# A "fitting" number of X's

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

I'm looking for a five-letter word.

---

```
       X X X X X
       X X X X X
       X X X X X 
       X X X X X
       X X X X X
       X X X X X
       X X X X X
       X X X X X
       X X X X X
       X X X X X
       X X X X X 
       X X X X X  
       X X X X X
       X X X X X 
       X X X X X
       X X X X X
       X X X X X
       X X X X X
       X X X X X
       X X X X X
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

**(5)**

**(8)**

**(6)**

**(6)**

Comment: After seeing a lot of your puzzles, I have to say. I really enjoy them. Often times I get completely baffled and take a while to begin, but they feel very satisfying to solve. And although they may not be that complex, I still think they are a nice refresher and I enjoy trying to solve them very much :)

Comment: @Auribouros Thanks, I appreciate your comment :) Yeah, I usually try to keep it quite simple but not that easy to spot. Some  easier than others ofc but in general I try to do so. Good luck on this one!

Comment: some of the grid's lines are thicker than others. I am assuming that's unintentional/unrelated to the puzzle?

Comment: @A.O. Yes, unintentional. Ignore the thickness etc. They're all suppose to have the same size.

Comment: Hm, just missing (what I assume to be) the last part, hopefully no one will have solved this by the time I get home..

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The five-letter word is:

> **SUITS**.

The numbered blocks of empty cells ...

> ... can be removed from the grid of X's. The tens (and hundereds) of the numbers are the rows and the ones are the columns where the respective cell should be placed. We get:
>
> ```
>            X X X X X
>            X . . . .
>            X . . . .
>            X . . . .
>       5    X X X X X
>            X X X X .
>            X . . . X
>            X . . . X
>            X . . . X
>      10    X X X X .
>            X . . . X
>            X . . . X
>            X X X X X
>            X . . . X
>      15    X . . . X
>            X X X X X
>            X . . . .
>            X X X X X
>            . . . . X
>      20    X X X X X
> ```

The black and red blocks ...

> ... indicate that we can divide the cut-out block of X's into four equal parts. If we do this, we get four letters:
>
> ```
>            X X X X X
>            X . . . .
>            X . . . .
>            X . . . .
>            X X X X X
>
>            X X X X .
>            X . . . X
>            X . . . X
>            X . . . X
>            X X X X .
>
>            X . . . X
>            X . . . X
>            X X X X X
>            X . . . X
>            X . . . X
>
>            X X X X X
>            X . . . .
>            X X X X X
>            . . . . X
>            X X X X X
> ```

The four numbers ...

> ... enumerate words that begin with the corresponding letters:
>
>  black C: **CLUBS** (5)
>  red D: **DIAMONDS** (8)
>  red H: **HEARTS** (6)
>  black S: **SPADES** (6)
>
>  These are the classical **SUITS** in a pack of playing cards, so this is the final answer we are looking for. (The colours black and red correspond to the colours of the suits, of course.)

Oh, and the title:

> Something that suits is something that is fitting.

Comment: Everything looks good. Well done!